# Error: 'StatIdentity' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2' when calling ggmap in R

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to create a map of board members for my nonprofit using `ggmap`. I'm located in San Diego so my code is as follows:

```
mapPoints <- qmap('San Diego, CA', zoom = 10) + 
             geom_point(data = membershipClean, 
                        aes(x = lon, y = lat, stat = "identity", size = Dues.Amount), 
                        alpha = .5)
```

Where `lat` and `lon` are the members' geocoded latitude and longitude respectively, and `Dues.Amount` is the numeric value by which I want the points scaled. When I run this code it throws the error:

> Error: 'StatIdentity' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2'"

I can't find anyone else online who is having the same problem. I'm a new user of `ggmap` but I am following the tutorials I've found online pretty much line by line, so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: What is your version of `ggplot2` and how old are the tutorials you are following. Some changes have been introduced in the version `2.0.0` of `ggplot2`, possibly making the tutorials obsolete.

Comment: I have ggplot2 2.0.0, but now that you mention it the tutorials are fairly old. Do you have any idea how I could clean it up and make it work?

Comment: Please provide some data (`membershipClean`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. It is fixed in the dev version of ggmap. 
Install it using devtools:

```
library(devtools)
install_github('ggmap','dkahle')
```

Restart session, load packages, and it should work

Comment: I had the same problem and this worked for me as well, thanks!

Comment: The newer version of install_github wants `install_github('dkahle/ggmap')`.