# How should I deal with "'someFunction' is not an exported object from 'namespace:somePackage'" error?

Tags: r, namespaces, package, r-faq

I have this error:

> 'someFunction' is not an exported object from 'namespace:somePackage'

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some reasons:

- Function is not part of the package, anymore, try `??someFunction` to find out which package it belongs to.
- Package data is not part of the package
- Function is available in newer version of the package, reinstall latest version.

See also these questions referring to specific instances of this problem:

- [Error: 'use_package' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60506182)
- ['data' is not an exported object from 'namespace:my_package'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46837428)
- [Error: 'st_normalize' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sf' when using 'geom_sf()'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58910056)
- [R Error: 'overlay' is not an exported object from 'namespace:sp'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56091313)
- ['stopwords' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tokenizers'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54894888)
- [Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr' in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49964166)
- [R package Error: 'encode_colour' is not an exported object from 'namespace:farver'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59960329)
- [R Markdown Error: 'is_latex_output' is not an exported object from 'namespace:knitr'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49140030)
- [Error: 'StatIdentity' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggplot2' when calling ggmap in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35051374)
- [Data not exported from namespace in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40364061)

Comment: similar: `oob_squish` not found in scales version 1.1.0, but is found in 1.1.1.  Does this require a shiny server restart when a new package version is installed?

Comment: Yes. shiny server restart required for new package version (and related functions) to be recognized.