# R: 'ggpredict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:predict3d' I tried it, and it is still part of the package (see pic) what can I do?

Tags: r

So I basically try to use the predict3d package to plot the results of a `glm`. I found out I should use `ggpredict` for it.

However I always get the error:

```
library(predict3d)
plot(predict3d::ggpredict(mymodel,c("x","x")))
```

---> **Error: 'ggpredict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:predict3d'**

Following this question: [How should I deal with "'someFunction' is not an exported object from 'namespace:somePackage'" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506879/how-should-i-deal-with-somefunction-is-not-an-exported-object-from-namespace)

I think I did what I can. [image]

I have the most current version

```
utils::packageVersion("predict3d")
[1] ‘0.1.3.3’
```

Is there anything I could do?

Comment: I think you meant to use `predict3d::ggPredict()` and not `predict3d::ggpredict()`.

Comment: Oh, it's within-word case sensitive? I didn't know that. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RonakShah can you make an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is case sensitive, the function that you are looking for is `ggPredict()` which is available in the `predict3d` package.